# javascript disable excel save button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this:

```
<div class="openexcel"> <a href="./xxxxx.xls"> Open excel file </a></div>
```

I have added this code too:

```
$('.openexcel').click(function(){
/* some code here*/
});
```

Is there any way or any code to add to javascript where I can stop the "save" button  once  the excel file is opened.

I need the user to read and see but I don't want him to "save" or "save as"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible, especially not using javascript.

Once the user opens up the excel document, it is open on their local machine, from their local cache.

You won't have any control over the functions available within their Excel software.

When making data available over the web, you need to accept that there is not a way of preventing people from keeping hold of this data.